# Missing "Go to Definition" from VSCode menu

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

I am working on Typescript/Javascript project using VSCODE. I use to hover mouse on the method and can see the function definition, `cmd + click` go the definition. Somehow(I don't know what I did), the "Go to Definition" disappear from the right click menu.
This is what I got right now.

Search a lot on Google, tried add `editor.multipleCursor: ctrlCmd` but it is not working as well.

Anyone has similar situation.

[image]

Comment: The same thing happened to me right now. Have you found a solution?

Answer (score 5):

In my case it was:
https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/142564#issuecomment-1041004004

```
Also make sure you have not disabled the built-in typescript extension:

In the extensions view
Search @builtin typescript
Make sure TypeScript and JavaScript Language Features is enabled
```

Comment: That did it for me. Not sure how it got disabled (it was working for the last 2 years and then suddenly a few weeks ago stopped). Enabling "Typescript and JavaScript Features" brought my "Go To Definition" back to the right-click menu :-) No need for a restart.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue today, some answers online pointed out that this is a problem with extensions, but each blame different one.
What worked for me is reinstalling these extensions: python, c/c++, git history, then restarting VSCode.
Maybe for your situation you need to uninstall different extensions and install them again, especially (but not limited to) recent ones.

Comment: It was githistory for me this time on MacOS

Comment: for me it was Tabnine

Answer (score 1):

My friend had the same issue, even after disabling all extension, reloading then and re-enabling them, it didn't solve the issue. However, after disabling, reloading and re-enabling, a prompt for missing dependencies showed up. Best to follow that prompt and install what's needed unless you know what you're doing.

My friend did not install dotnet on their pc. After installing dotnet, then again, disabling, reloading and re-enabling all extensions, it works.

Answer (score 0):

fast answer: if is WSL installed verific dotnet version betwen systems. i had to match them...

Answer (score 0):

I reinstalled my Python Extension and everything got back as it was before. Try to delete unneeded extensions and update your Python Extension.