# VScode right click misses limited and Go to definition and more are not working

Tags: c, visual-studio-code, reference

I have a project in C language, and many options I used to do are not working anymore.

For example:

- CTRL + hover: doesn't show the definition.
- CTRL + click: doesn't go to the definition.
- Right click menu is very limited
  [image]
- Outline doesn't work.
  [image]

I have already tried the next things:

- Remove .vscode from the folder.
- Open a new workspace.
- Reinstall VScode.
- Disable all extensions.

Thank for help,

Linux version: Ubuntu 18.04
VScode version: 1.71.2

Extensions list:

- better-comments v3.0.2
- better-cpp-syntax v1.15.19
- code-settings-sync v3.4.3
- CppSnippets v0.0.15
- cpptools-themes v1.0.0
- kite v0.147.0
- perforce v4.15.5
- remote-containers v0.251.0
- remote-ssh v0.84.0
- remote-ssh-edit v0.80.0
- remote-wsl v0.66.3

Comment: Is the source file part of the current project?

Comment: I think so. As far as I understood, in vscode there is no real project, they have a workspace, and all files are listed under the workspace. 

How can check it, if I am wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I found that the settings sync deleted all the C/Cpp extensions by mistake, which is why I didn't have any of the above.

Answer (score 0):

Uninstall C/C++ extension works for me. Based on the answer from @stephw from this post [Missing "Go to Definition" from VSCode menu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69639736/missing-go-to-definition-from-vscode-menu)

Comment: this might be when you should vote to close as a duplicate (except you don't have flagging privileges yet)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).